# Proving a geometric relation in 2D Minkowski spacetime

Tags: special-relativity, algebraic-geometry

[image: picture triangle]

The triangle on the picture is the (future) causal domain of dependence of the interval of length $A$. The intervals of length $B$ and $C$ are relatively boosted to each other. How do I prove that $AD=BC$?

Comment: By AD do you mean (Length of interval A) $\times$ (Length of interval D)?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Reviewers: [related meta suggestion](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/note-why-the-migration-close-reasons-are-stronger-as-the-others)